# Handling Multiple URL in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, url, android-webview

Im trying to monitor the following 2 URL's, and if they ARE NOT the following URL's then do something. This seems like its very simple to do, however i need somone else to take a look.

The code below is not working - its only "monitoring" the first URL

```
@Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view,
            String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("http://www.google.com") &&
            url.startsWith("http://www.bing.com"))
               view.loadUrl(url);
               progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ..
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the question by simplying changing && to ||.

```
 @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view,
        String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("http://www.google.com") || url.startsWith("http://www.bing.com")) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        ..
    }
    return true;
```